# A SWAT van with Raptors attacking it?

Tags: time-travel, dinosaurs, police

I want to know if a SWAT Lenco BearCat van that got teleported to a different world where a group of a few dozen raptors starts attacking the van. Would the van be able to survive about eight hours without being broken into by Velociraptors?

The raptors will not stop attacking.

The swat members have no idea whatsoever about what is happening.

They must make contact with the portal that opens after eight hours.

Comment: When you say 'SWAT van' are you referring to a Ford Escort estate MK1 in blue with a mag-mount blue light - of the nineteen seventies, or some other beast? When you say raptor-lookalikes are you referring to Kestrels? They might be curious about the scratching noise on the roof, but why would you think there might be an issue, unless they get hungry with waiting of-course, or need a pee.

Comment: I concur with Rottweiler, you need to be more specific. By raptors do you mean Deinonychus? What kind of SWAT van? How can the SWAT members make contact with those making the portal and how is that relevant to your question? Once you clear things up, I'm sure you'll get answers to your question.

Comment: It's not really a world building question. It's more a plot question. You have a plot idea about whether this vehicle survives, so you put on the armor, weapons, etc., that lets them survive.

Comment: Sorry about the mess about the question I will fix it shortly                                                 .                                                                                                                                                . UPDATE: fixed it now.

Comment: There's still an important detail here.  Are you referring to the fictional raptors as pictured in Jurassic Park (that do not exist)?  Or do you mean the ones that were the size of a turkey that actually existed?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'raptors'? We're still at Kestrels or F22s, as per my comment before you edited. Please clarify. You would also need to edit-in details of what a 'Lenco BearCat' is, in relevant detail.

Comment: I mean the bird-raptors.

Comment: can there be some specs provided for less googling(maybe), idk as a bottom part of q

Answer (score 3):

**Yes if you could get the van up to speed.**

If the van appeared and was high centered on some rocks, and the SWAT team
tenaciously had no idea what was going on such that they did not fight back as the raptors got thru the windows, the SWAT team would be in trouble.

But if the SWAT van appeared on I80 it could just drive.  The van could outrun the raptors.  I know the raptors would set off after it because they will not stop attacking.  Once the van got a little distance it could turn around and come back at the raptors.  This is a doughty van and hitting the raptors at 60 miles per hours will be ok for the van and sort most of the raptors out.  If some were still interested in chasing the van, the van could repeat this maneuver.

I have to think that you would need seriously intoxicated SWAT team members to not get some rough idea of what was going on when a monster poked its bitey head thru the window and starting making biting motions.  And biting sounds, and probably drool.   It is a pretty weak SWAT team that does not have fighting equipment of some kind in the van.  I expect they would use some of that stuff on the monster's heads.